# Delphi XE5 FireMonkey TstringGrid cells don't accept keyboard input

Tags: delphi, grid, delphi-xe5, stringgrid

I am using a TStringGrid which is placed on a popup (TPopup). when the user click a button the popup will appear with the stringGrid. user will then insert some data in the cells then clicking an apply button on the popup which will update a data array.
the popup is used as a metro style flyout as per firemonkey sample.

the problem is that the string grid appears put when trying to edit a cell it doesn't accept any input from the key board.

Any idea how to solve this problem. I am using Delphi XE5.

Comment: check the Enabled, ReadOnly, TabStop properties for a start.

Comment: @Sam, Enabled:=True and ReadOnly:=False. TabStop cannot find any property with that name. if you mean taborder it is 0. however the problem still exist.

Comment: Edit the question to include your dfm and pas files (or their FireMonkey equivalent). Check the Options property of your StringGrid. If your StringGrid has a KeyPressed event handler then implement it (just double-click it and write some dummy code inside just so you can step through it and inspect the Key or Char input parameter - I can't remember the exact name). How long have you been programming in Delphi? Are you saying that you can actually click into the cell successfully but then it doesn't accept keyboard input, or that you can't even get the cursor to appear in the StringGrid's cell?

Comment: You may be interested in following this current question regarding a similar scenario. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20890373/allowing-keyboard-input-to-a-firemonkey-tedit-nested-inside-a-firemonkey-tpopup

Comment: @Sam,I used Popup1.Pop(true) instead of Popup.IsOpen(true) to show the popup and it worked. i now can edit the text cell. however when i am trying to close the popup by clicking outside it doesn't close, any ideas?

Comment: I don't know anything about FireMonkey but since when does a popup close just by clicking outside of it! There is a ClosePopup method http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/FMX.Controls.TPopup.ClosePopup that might help. Over and out. This question is now a duplicate and probably will be closed soon.